# How can i write to the USB OTG Controller Registers on the HPS part of the DE1-SOC board?

Tags: arm, embedded, usb, usb-otg, soc

Currently i am working on the USB port of the DE1-SOC board. I tried to understand how USB 2.0 works, however when it comes to the DE1-SOC board, as I understand, controllers on the HPS part of the SOC system are memmory mapped for us to control their functionalities.

Right now, I can acccess to the memmory mapped devices such as 7-segment displays, pushbutton keys, and slider switches, however i can not access and write to the registers of the USB OTG Controller and thus I can not use the USB functionality of the board.

Here is what I did for at this point:

pinmux() : Makes the connections between the pins of the SOC and USB ULPI device.

```
void pinmux(void) {

// pinmux configuration, hooking USB0 connections up.
*(SYSMGR_FLASHIO0_ptr)          =   0x00000002;     // Pin Connection For D0
*(SYSMGR_FLASHIO0_ptr + 0x4)    =   0x00000002;     // Pin Connection For D1
*(SYSMGR_FLASHIO0_ptr + 0x8)    =   0x00000002;     // Pin Connection For D2
*(SYSMGR_FLASHIO0_ptr + 0xC)    =   0x00000002;     // Pin Connection For D3
*(SYSMGR_FLASHIO0_ptr + 0x10)   =   0x00000002;     // Pin Connection For D4
*(SYSMGR_FLASHIO0_ptr + 0x14)   =   0x00000002;     // Pin Connection For D5
*(SYSMGR_FLASHIO0_ptr + 0x18)   =   0x00000002;     // Pin Connection For D6
*(SYSMGR_FLASHIO0_ptr + 0x1C)   =   0x00000002;     // Pin Connection For D7
*(SYSMGR_FLASHIO0_ptr + 0x20)   =   0x00000002;     // Pin Connection For CLK
*(SYSMGR_FLASHIO0_ptr + 0x24)   =   0x00000002;     // Pin Connection For STP
*(SYSMGR_FLASHIO0_ptr + 0x28)   =   0x00000002;     // Pin Connection For DIR
}
```

config_usb() : Configures the USB controller, tries to power up the USB port.

```
void config_usb(void) {

*(SYSMGR_USBL3MASTER_ptr)       =   0x0000005F;             // Makes USB0 : priviledged, bufferable, and cacheable
*(SYSMGR_USB0ECC_ptr)           =   0x00000001;             // Enables ECC

*(USB0_HPRT_ptr)                =   0x00001000;             // Power up the port
}
```

In the config_usb(), I can access to the SYSMGR Registers (System Manager Registers) however i cannot access to USB controller registers, USB0_HPRT in this case.

The main purpose of my struggle is to plug a usb mouse to one of the ports and display it on a VGA screen. ( I can access and control the VGA port as well. )

At this point, I don't know what am I missing and I am kind of lost in the documentations.
Here I am seeking help at the end point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this board, but it appears form https://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=205&No=836&PartNo=4 that it normally runs a Linus distribution.  In which case the USB HID will already be supported b the operating system, and the OS will protect the USB controller from directs access by user level code.

If you are attempting to support USB on "bare-metal" do not underestimate how complex a USB host stack and HID driver can be, but to access the controller you will need to map its physical memory space to the virtual map via the MMU.

Comment: Yes, that is the board I am working on. I am not currently running any distribution on the board, I need to implement this on "bare-metal". I am not trying to support USB in a complete manner, I am just trying to implement the USB host stack and a basic HID driver for a usb mouse. Could not understand the virtual mapping you mentioned. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @OğuzDemirhan The ARM9 has am MMU, if that has been enabled, only regional explicitly mapped will be accessible. That may not apply in this case.  How have you observed that you cannot access the registers?  Are you certain that the device is memory mapped?

Comment: The USB OTG Controller and its registers are documented in [Cyclone V Hard Processor System Technical Reference Manual](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/hb/cyclone-v/cv_54001.pdf). I am using "Intel FPGA Monitor Program" to compile and load the program that I write. It works in debug mode and shows the memory content of the running session. Here i can see that i can change other memory mapped device's registers such as i2c but cannot change the USB OTG Controller's registers. Thanks for the clarification on MMU, i will check it.